# css ul li разное расстояние между столбцами

Tags: css, ul

```css
ul {
  height: 100%;
  columns: 3;
  column-gap: 84px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ssdfsd</li>
  <li>2ttrw</li>
  <li>wecv</li>
  <li>34t3t334 gfgfg</li>
  <li>rg t43t rgrg</li>
  <li>rfh;k0</li>
  <li>sf9sdy9</li>
  <li>f fd98 sdl</li>
  <li>pop</li>
  <li>g9e8</li>
  <li>sdf sd0f98</li>
  <li>sdfkv09 90 s0</li>
  <li>nv 8s</li>
</ul>
```

Задача в том, что бы было три колонки (это есть), но расстояние между 2й и 3й должно быть больше, чем между 1й и 2й.
Как такое можно сделать с CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  height: 100%;
  columns: 3;
  column-gap: 84px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.two{padding-right:50px;padding-left:0px!important;}
.three{padding-right:0px!important;padding-left:50px!important;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="one">ssdfsd</li>
  <li class="one">2ttrw</li>
  <li class="one">wecv</li>
  <li class="one">34t3t334 gfgfg</li>
  <li class="one">rg t43t rgrg</li>
  <li class="two">rfh;k0</li>
  <li class="two">sf9sdy9</li>
  <li class="two">f fd98 sdl</li>
  <li class="two">pop</li>
  <li class="two">g9e8</li>
  <li class="three">sdf sd0f98</li>
  <li class="three">sdfkv09 90 s0</li>
  <li class="three">nv 8s</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: СпасиБо! но желательно, что бы автоматически к любым элементам попадающим в третюю колонку, или в ее область по расстоянию имели большее расстояние ко второй колонке...

Comment: Используя `Jade` я добавил дополнительный класс к последней трети элементов (деля общее количество на 3). Жаль, красивее способа не нашел, с чистым `css`

Answer (score 0):

Возможно существует более простое решение, но я бы воспользовался плагином [autocolumnlist](https://github.com/Neolot/jQuery.AutoColumnList). Он разобьет ваш список на три столбца, у каждого из них будет класс `.column`, и с помощью  псевдокласса `:nth-of-type` Вы сможете стилизировать каждую из имеющихся колонок.

Comment: СпасиБо! плагины не использую в данном случае. :nth-of-type или что подобное может как-то и поможет, нужно подумать...

Comment: Если кол-во эл-тов в списке известно, то псевдокласс решит проблему. В противном случае, боюсь, исключительно средствами `css` её не решить.